# Python 3 ttk.Spinbox format option

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, format, ttk

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('vista')

spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=100, increment=5, format='%10.2f')
spinbox.set('{:10.2f} %'.format(0))  # default value

spinbox.pack()

root.minsize(400, 100)  # make window larger for ease of finding for this simple example
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to add a literal percent symbol to the `ttk.Spinbox` option *format='%10.2f'*. So when you increment or decrement the values there is always a % symbol displayed after the value. This seems painfully difficult to achieve and I presume it is me at fault missing something that is very simplistic/obvious. You can add any string here and it works but it does not work with a literal % symbol since the string value given to the option format contains a % symbol which it is required to have.

The first thing I tried was escaping the % symbol I want to display and it did not work, for example: `format='%10.2f\\%'`.

I have in my ability tried everything I can think of in the format option but I cannot show a % symbol. This is not a really an issue but would be a nice to have if anyone knows of a solution, thank you.

Comment: I am getting `module 'tkinter.ttk' has no attribute 'Spinbox'`. When I change `ttk.Spinbox` to `tk.Spinbox`, I am getting `'Spinbox' object has no attribute 'set'`. What version of Python do you have?

Comment: Looks like Spinbox is in ttk since 3.7, and I am currently on a machine with 3.5, so I can't reproduce.

Comment: It appears that you are correct, although tk.Spinbox has been an available widget since Python 2.3. I tried the same example above slightly modified for tk.Spinbox and the format option differs slightly by the fact it does not let you add any other text to the format option or the program crashes. This leads me to believe that with tk.Spinbox my question is not possible but there is still hope for ttk.Spinbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I installed Python 3.7.3 and found a solution. You have to use `%%` in the format string to get a literal `%`. However, setting the initial value by e.g. `spinbox.set(0.0)` doesn't automatically apply the format, although the [docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_spinbox.htm#M18) says it should.

Comment: well that was simple as I expected... I don't think I would have ever though of using double percent symbols. I just use `spinbox.set('{:10.2f} %'.format(0))` to get the percent symbols shown for the default value display. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass `ttk.Spinbox` to alter its behavior, in order to display the format you wish, alongside a unit in the spinbox entry:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class FormattedSpinbox(ttk.Spinbox):
    """A ttk.Spinbox that displays a float with 2 decimals,
    alongside a '%' character unit
    """
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        kwargs['command'] = self.command
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
    def set(self, value):
        super().set(value)
        self.command()
    def get(self):
        return float(super().get().strip().split()[0])
    def command(self):
        value = self.get()
        self.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.insert(0, f'{float(value): 10.2f} %')


root = tk.Tk()

spinoptions = {'from_': 0, 'to': 100, 'increment': 5}
spinbox = FormattedSpinbox(root, **spinoptions)
spinbox.set(0)  # default value
spinbox.pack()

root.minsize(400, 100)
root.mainloop()
```

#### the widget looks like this:

[image]

Alternatively, if you wanted to parametrize the format, you could do like this. Note that `str(value).format(format)` is not entirely equivalent to `f'{float(value): 10.2f} %')`; the former does not add white space to fill the required width, and the number of decimals is at least one, up to the required number, if the value carries enough precision.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class FormattedSpinbox(ttk.Spinbox):
    """A ttk.Spinbox that displays a float with 2 decimals,
    alongside a '%' character unit
    """
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        kwargs['command'] = self.command
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
    def set(self, value):
        super().set(value)
        self.command()
    def get(self):
        return float(super().get().strip().split()[0])
    def command(self):
        value = self.get()
        self.delete(0, tk.END)
        svalue = str(value).format(format)
        self.insert(0, f'{svalue} %')


root = tk.Tk()

spinoptions = {'from_': 0, 'to': 100, 'increment': 5, 'format':'%10.2f'}
spinbox = FormattedSpinbox(root, **spinoptions)
spinbox.set(0)  # default value
spinbox.pack()

root.minsize(400, 100)
root.mainloop()
```

#### the widget appearance now is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make one that works when a user types in the box or when they click on the spin button. It's not the most streamlined, but seems to work well enough.

```
class FormattingSpinBox(ttk.Spinbox):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, from_=0, to=100, command=self.command, **kwargs)
        self.displayValue = 2.5
        self.registerValidation()

    def registerValidation(self):
        self.configure(validate='all', validatecommand=(self.register(self.validation), '%i', '%P', '%s', '%V'))

    def validation(self, index, text, previousText, eventType):
        if eventType == 'focusin':
            self.focusInValidation(text)
            return True

        if eventType == 'key':

            if int(index) >= len(text) - 1:
                self.focusInValidation(previousText)

            return True

        return True

    def focusInValidation(self, text):

        self.icursor(len(text) - 2)
        self.displayValue = self.value

    @property
    def displayValue(self):
        return self.get()

    @property
    def value(self):
        try:
            return float(self.get()[:-2])
        except ValueError:
            return 0

    @displayValue.setter
    def displayValue(self, val):
        self.set(f'{float(val):4.2f} %')

    def command(self):
        self.displayValue = self.displayValue
```